# Helm is not deleting pod after Helm del --purge

Tags: kubernetes, hook, kubernetes-helm

I am trying helm del --purge  which not deleting one pod which is mentioned in a yaml separately, but it is deleting all the pods which are getting created by deployments or which are stateful pods.

Comment: show the yaml defining the pod that is not being deleted

Answer (score 4):

helm del --purge `<helm chart name>` will delete only pods which are related with particular helm charts.

You can check all the helm charts installed on the cluster via : `helm ls`

you can delete helm chart using `helm del <chart name>`

while the pods are created separately and not part of any helm chart will not be deleted when you will run  `helm del --purge`

So, for example, you installed MySQL using helm : `helm install --name mysql stable/mysql`

So when you will run `helm del --purge mysql` it will only delete mysql pods.

To delete the pod which are created separately you can run `kubectl delete pod <pod name>`

> To delete the deployment : `kubectl delete deployment <deployment name>`
>
> To delete statefulsets : `kubectl delete statefulset <statefulset name>`

Comment: It's inside my chart only. Whatever pods are getting  created by deployment are getting deleted but we have another yml for creation of a pod. Which is not getting deleted on helm delete

Comment: You could try the delete with `--purge --no-hooks` there was bug in helm release so better best checck the version of helm